# Create many very similar (lazy loaded) feature modules without rewriting lots of code in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I want to write an application with many subpages in Angular, which are supposed to have the same substructure and their own routing:

```
./subpage1/topicA
./subpage1/topicB
./subpage1/topicC
...
./subpage2/topicA
./subpage2/topicB
./subpage2/topicC
...
```

As there will be many of those subpages and some might be relatively big I want to pack everyone into a lazy loaded feature module to reduce loading time.

My main goal is to make the whole construct as light and maintanable as possible. For example I don't want to rewrite the routing and other basic structures for every subpage and want to be able to change stuff (like general structure or the names of the subroutes) without touching every subpage-module. Is there a way to do that?